# If a list is found in another list?

Tags: scheme, racket

I started to learn Racket and I don't know how to check if a list is found in another list. Something like (member x (list 1 2 3 x 4 5)), but I want that "x" to be a a sequence of numbers.

I know how to implement recursive, but I would like to know if it exists a more direct operator.

For example I want to know if (list 3 4 5) is found in (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 )

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this [Racket Object interface and](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objectutils.html) the `(is-a? v type) -> boolean` seems to be what you are looking for?, simply use it while looping to catch any results that are of a given type and do whatever with them

you may also want to look into `(subclass? c cls) -> boolean` from the same link, if you want to catch all List types in one go

should there be a possiblity of having a list inside a list, that was already inside a list(1,2,(3,4,(5,6))) i'm afraid that recursion is probally the best solution though, since given there is a possibility of an infinit amount of loops, it is just better to run the recursion on a list everytime you locate a new list in the original list, that way any given number of subList will still be processed

Comment: I think I understand the idea, but it's a little too advanced for my Racket's level :) Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for succeeding elements in a list:

```
(define (subseq needle haystack)
  (let loop ((index 0)
             (cur-needle needle)
             (haystack haystack))
    (cond ((null? cur-needle) index)
          ((null? haystack) #f)
          ((and (equal? (car cur-needle) (car haystack))
                (loop index (cdr cur-needle) (cdr haystack)))) ; NB no consequence
          (else (loop (add1 index) needle (cdr haystack))))))
```

This evaluates to the index where the elements of needle is first found in the haystack or `#f` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use some string functions to join the lists and compare them (recursion is needed):

```
(define (list-in-list l L)
  (define (fn ll)
    (string-join (map number->string ll))) ; Function to create a string out of list of numbers;  
  (define ss (fn l))                       ; Convert smaller list to string; 
  (let loop ((L L))                        ; Set up recursion and initial value; 
    (cond
      [(empty? L)    #f]                   ; If end of list reached, pattern is not present; 
      [(string-prefix? (fn L) ss) #t]      ; Compare if initial part of main list is same as test list;
      [else    (loop (rest L))])))         ; If not, loop with first item of list removed;
```

Testing:

```
(list-in-list (list 3 4 5) (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 ))
```

Output:

```
#t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp-match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html?q=regexp-match#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._regexp-match%29%29) to check if pattern is a substring of another string by converting both lists of numbers to strings, and comparing them, as such:

```
(define (member? x lst)
  (define (f lst)
    (foldr string-append "" (map number->string lst)))
  (if (regexp-match (f x) (f lst)) #t #f))
```

`f` converts lst (a list of numbers) to a string. `regexp-match` checks if `(f x)` is a pattern that appears in `(f lst)`.

For example,

```
> (member? (list 3 4 5) (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
#t
```

Answer (score -1):

straight from the Racket documentation:

> `(member v lst [is-equal?]) → (or/c list? #f)
>     v : any/c
>     lst : list?
>     is-equal? : (any/c any/c -> any/c) = equal?`

Locates the first element of lst that is equal? to v. If such an element exists, the tail of lst starting with that element is returned. Otherwise, the result is #f.

Or in your case:

> `(member '(3 4 5) (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))`

where x is  `'(3 4 5)` or `(list 3 4 5)` or `(cons 3 4 5)`

it will return `'(3 4 5 6 7)` if x (  searched list `'(3 4 5)` ) was found in the list or false (`#f`) if it was not found

or you can use assoc to check if your x is met in one of many lists, or :

> `(assoc x (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) (list x 6)))`

will return :

> '(x 6)

There are also lambda constructions but I will not go in depth since I am not very familiar with Racket yet. Hope this helps :)

EDIT: if `member` gives you different results than what you expect try using `memq` instead

Comment: I tried (member '(3 4 5) (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)) , but it doesn't work. Every time it gets #f .Thats why I posted here. It's a little strange that it doesn't work and I doesn't understand why. Thanks for response :) EDIT: same result with memq

Comment: `member` doesn't look for succeeding elements in the list but that one of the elements is `equal?`, thus `(member '(3 4 5) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)) ; ==> #f` while `(member '(3 4 5) '(1 3 (3 4 5) (6 7))) ; ==>((3 4 5) (6 7))`. `(cons 3 4 5)` will not work as it takes exactly 2 arguments.